# My module does not appear in the installed hooks

Tags: php, text, module, task-parallel-library, prestashop

I have created a module to add an extra text for each product and that can be edited from the backoffice and its text saved in the database so that when it is updated it remains saved, etc.

The question is that said form does not appear in any of the installed Hooks, any suggestions? Thanks!

My php code:

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

class MyModuleText extends Module
{
    protected $config_form = false;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'mymoduletext';
        $this->tab = 'administration';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'Jordi Comes';
        $this->need_instance = 0;

        /**
         * Set $this->bootstrap to true if your module is compliant with bootstrap (PrestaShop 1.6)
         */
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('My_Module_Text');
        $this->description = $this->l('Crea un texto editable desde el backoffice para cualquier producto de forma independiente');

        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
    }

    /**
     * Don't forget to create update methods if needed:
     * http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Enabling+the+Auto-Update
     */
    public function install()
    {
        include(dirname(__FILE__).'/sql/install.php');

       // Register hooks
       $this->registerHook('displayProductTabContent');
       $this->registerHook('actionProductUpdate');
       $this->registerHook('displayProductAdditionalInfo');
       $this->registerHook('header');

       return parent::install()
           && Configuration::updateValue('MYMODULETEXT_MODULE_NAME', 'producttextmodule');
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        include(dirname(__FILE__).'/sql/uninstall.php');

        // Unregister hooks
        $this->unregisterHook('actionProductUpdate');
        $this->unregisterHook('displayProductAdditionalInfo');
        $this->unregisterHook('header');

        return parent::uninstall()
            && Configuration::deleteByName('MYMODULETEXT_MODULE_NAME');
    }

   
    public function hookDisplayProductTabContent($params)
    {
        $productText = $this->getProductText((int)$params['product']['id_product']);

        $this->smarty->assign(array(
            'productText' => $productText,
        ));

        return $this->context->smarty->fetch($this->local_path.'../producttabcontent.tpl');
    }

    

    public function hookActionProductUpdate($params)
    {
        // Save custom text for product
        if (Tools::isSubmit('submitProductTextModule')) {
            $id_product = (int)$params['id_product'];
            $text = pSQL(Tools::getValue('mymoduletext'));
            
            if (isset($text)) {
                $sql = 'REPLACE INTO `'._DB_PREFIX_.'mymoduletext` (`id_product`, `text`) 
                VALUES ('.$id_product.', "'.$text.'")';
    
                Db::getInstance()->execute($sql);
            }
        }
    }

    public function hookDisplayProductAdditionalInfo($params)
{
    // Get custom text for product
    $id_product = (int)$params['product']['id_product'];
    $sql = 'SELECT `text` FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'mymoduletext` WHERE `id_product` = '.(int)$id_product;
    $text = Db::getInstance()->getValue($sql);
    

    if ($text === false) {
        return '';
    }

    // Display custom text in product information block
    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'mymoduletext' => $text,
    ));

    return $this->context->smarty->fetch($this->local_path.'../producttextmodule.tpl');
}

        
        public function hookHeader()
        {
            // Include CSS and JS files
            $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'views/css/producttextmodule.css');
            $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'views/js/producttextmodule.js');
        }
        
        public function getContent()
        {
            // Handle form submission
            $output = '';
            if (Tools::isSubmit('submitProductTextModule')) {
                $my_module_name = strval(Tools::getValue('MYMODULETEXT_MODULE_NAME'));
                if (!$my_module_name
                    || empty($my_module_name)
                    || !Validate::isGenericName($my_module_name)
                ) {
                    $output .= $this->displayError($this->l('Invalid Configuration value'));
                } else {
                    Configuration::updateValue('MYMODULETEXT_MODULE_NAME', $my_module_name);
                    $output .= $this->displayConfirmation($this->l('Settings updated'));
                }
            }
        
            // Display form
            return $output.$this->displayForm();
        }
        
        public function displayForm()
        {
            // Get default language
            $default_lang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
        
            // Init Fields form array
            $fields_form[0]['form'] = array(
                'legend' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Settings'),
                ),
                'input' => array(
                    array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => $this->l('Configuration value'),
                        'name' => 'MYMODULETEXT_MODULE_NAME_MODULE_NAME',
                        'size' => 20,
                        'required' => true
                    )
                ),
                'submit' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Save'),
                    'class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right'
                )
            );
        
            $helper = new HelperForm();
        
            // Module, token and currentIndex
            $helper->module = $this;
            $helper->name_controller = $this->name;
            $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
            $helper->currentIndex = AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name;
        
            
            // Language
        
        $languages = Language::getLanguages(false);
        $helper->default_form_language = $default_lang;
        $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = $default_lang;
        $helper->languages = $languages;

            // Title and toolbar
    $helper->title = $this->displayName;
    $helper->show_toolbar = true;       
    $helper->toolbar_scroll = true;      
    $helper->submit_action = 'submitProductTextModule';
    $helper->toolbar_btn = array(
        'save' =>
            array(
                'desc' => $this->l('Save'),
                'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name.'&save'.$this->name.
                    '&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
            ),
        'back' => array(
            'href' => AdminController::$currentIndex.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules'),
            'desc' => $this->l('Back to list')
        )
    );

    // Load current value
    $helper->fields_value['MYMODULETEXT_MODULE_NAME'] = Configuration::get('MYMODULETEXT_MODULE_NAME');

    return $helper->generateForm($fields_form);
}
}

?>


<div class="product-text-module">
    <form action="{$link->getAdminLink('AdminProducts')}&id_product={$product.id_product}&updateproduct" method="post">
        <textarea name="mymoduletext" id="mymoduletext">{$productText}</textarea>
        <button type="submit" name="submitProductTextModule" class="btn btn-default">{l s='Save'}</button>
    </form>
</div>

{literal}
<style>

.product-text-module {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
</style>
{/literal}




<div class="product-text-module">
    <p>{$mymoduletext}</p>
</div>

{literal}
<style>

.product-text-module {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

</style>
{/literal}
```

```
All sugestions accepted
```

Answer (score 0):

If your module installed correctly in the hook,
Try this:

```
$this->fetch('module:producttextmodule/producttextmodule.tpl');
```